# Find a cost-sensitive multiclass algorithm

Tags: classification, boosting, multi-class, weights, threshold

I am working on decision trees which can directly work in a multiclass context. My aim is reduce the misclassification's errors of a decision tree by improving its ability to tackle imbalanced datasets and by turning this base classifier into a cost-sensitive learner so that the cost of misclassifying an observation of class i as an example of class j will be taken into account (that's to say that the cost of misclassifying an observation of class i should not be independent of the predicted class label).

I was thinking of methods including thresholds' shifting, weighting or even cost-sensitive boosting algorithms but I can't seem to find a lot of information about these issues related to multiclass problems and not just binary problems.

Do you have any ideas how this goal might be achieved?